# boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group does not work

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I tried the  [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp), but it does not work. Apparently it does not set IPPROTO_IP/IP_MULTICAST_IF option. I can only find boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface for IPPROTO_IP/IP_MULTICAST_IF, I tried but failed. Is there any way to make boost::asio::ip::multicast work without calling c-level setsockopt?

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(
    listen_address, multicast_port);
socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

// Join the multicast group.
socket_.set_option(
    boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));
```

Comment: use `multicast::join_group(multicast_address, listen_endpoint.address().to_v4())`.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. Just tried, and we must set "0.0.0.0" to listen_endpoint. So the working version is 
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(udp::v4(), multicast_port);
...
  socket_.set_option(multicast::join_group(address::from_string(group_).to_v4(),
        address::from_string(interface).to_v4()));

Comment: @Stefan post your comment as an answer

Comment: I had this problem, but answers didn't helped me (even if they're interesting). Instead, the following question helped me: [What does it mean to bind a multicast (udp) socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692956/what-does-it-mean-to-bind-a-multicast-udp-socket) (added here for potential future readers).

Answer (score 9):

Correct Answer:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(udp::v4(), multicast_port); 
...
socket_.set_option(multicast::join_group(
  address::from_string(multicast_address).to_v4(), 
  address::from_string(interface).to_v4()));
```

Comment: interface is actually your local address to filter incoming packets.

Comment: This saves me in multiple addresses machines.

Comment: I've submitted an update to the sample code; you can find the pull request (and the updated samples) [here](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/pull/390).

Answer (score 9):

I think there's an error in [boost example code for udp multicast](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-2.html).

In the example code they bind socket to local interface but for udp multicast you have to bind to the udp multicast group IP and port.

```
socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);
```

should be:

```
socket_.bind(
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint( multicast_address, multicast_port ) );
```

see [multicast howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-2.html):

> ... for a process to receive multicast datagrams it has to ask the kernel
>   to join the group and bind the port those datagrams were being sent
>   to. The UDP layer uses both the destination address and port to
>   demultiplex the packets and decide which socket(s) deliver them to ...
>
> ... it is necessary to advise the kernel which multicast groups we are
>   interested in. That is, we have to ask the kernel to "join" those
>   multicast groups ...

check if you joined the group on correct interface with `netstat -g | grep <multicast_group_ip>`

this is I believe incorrect boost example code:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(
    listen_address, multicast_port);
socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

// Join the multicast group.
socket_.set_option(
    boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));

socket_.async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
    boost::bind(&receiver::handle_receive_from, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Comment: In my testing, that's what it takes to get it working under Linux, but @poordeveloper's answer works under MS Windows. Not sure why.