# Boost.Asio throws 'No such device' exception when trying to join multicast group

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio

Following code throws exception `"No such device"`,
when trying to join the multicast group (`set_option` call).

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(){
    const std::string recv_addr = "232.4.130.147";
    const int recv_port = 31338;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint recv_endpoint(
                boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(recv_addr),
                recv_port);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket recv_sock(io_service, recv_endpoint);

    recv_sock.set_option(
            boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(
                boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(recv_addr).to_v4()
                ));
}
```

It happens no matter, whether network-manager is running or not. And with no regard to IP address set.

The problem arises when I connect to an internal network with IP address manually set. 
On the other network, where IP is obtained from DHCP I observe no problem.

I have `eth0` interface up all the time and this is the only active, non-local interface.

I've tried specifying listen interface as [it was shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675623/boostasioipmulticastjoin-group-does-not-work), but I got an exception `"Invalid argument"` instead, and the Boost.Asio documentation [is not saying anything about setting the interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__multicast__join_group.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With no DHCP working, there is no route for multicast.

Use:

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth0
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that it is possible to get around this with some manual trickery using AF_PACKET, but for most cases not worth the trouble.