# Boost asio set_option error

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I tried to run the following program with argument 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 in redhat, and I got "Exception: set_option: Invalid argument" error at  socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));

It also tried to run it in window, and it work fine in vc++. I am running out of idea. Please help me out.

```
//
// receiver.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

const short multicast_port = 30001;

class receiver
{
public:
  receiver(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const boost::asio::ip::address& listen_address,
      const boost::asio::ip::address& multicast_address)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
    // Create the socket so that multiple may be bound to the same address.
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(
        listen_address, multicast_port);
    socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
    socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

    **// Join the multicast group.
    socket_.set_option(
        boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address)); <-- Error**

    socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&receiver::handle_receive_from, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_receive_from(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_recvd)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      std::cout.write(data_, bytes_recvd);
      std::cout << std::endl;

      socket_.async_receive_from(
          boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
          boost::bind(&receiver::handle_receive_from, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: receiver <listen_address> <multicast_address>\n";
      std::cerr << "  For IPv4, try:\n";
      std::cerr << "    receiver 0.0.0.0 239.255.0.1\n";
      std::cerr << "  For IPv6, try:\n";
      std::cerr << "    receiver 0::0 ff31::8000:1234\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    receiver r(io_service,
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[1]),
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[2]));
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should not use local ip. it is not an multicast ip format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should not use local ip. it is not an multicast ip format

Answer (score 1):

From [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8675623/478288), you need

```
socket_.set_option(
    boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address.to_v4()));
```

That is, append `.to_v4()` on your `ip::address` variable.

Comment: Thanks. I also did some searching from google. This solution couldn't resolve my error.
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address.to_v4()));

Comment: @BryanFok When you create `listen_endpoint`, do you pass `listen_address.to_v4()` as well? I notice the linked question uses `udp::v4()`.

Comment: Just tried. boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(
   listen_address.to_v4(), multicast_port);. Same error